# .NET Core, EF.Core - two ways data encryption

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a question about right approach in data encryption.
I used to use Column Encryption which is not supported in EF.Core yet.

Do yo have any ideas how to encrypt data in both ways (client - sever, server-client)?
I can manually encrypt data on client side and then decrypt on server side using stored procedure, but i wanted to have it automatized.

Database is on SQL Server 2017, application .net core 2.0

Thanks for suggestions